# How to get NSDictionary from NSURLSessionDataTask

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest, nsurlsessiondatatask

```
-(NSDictionary *)fetchFromUrl:(NSString *)url{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest  requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                  dataFetched = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                           options:0
                                                                                             error:NULL];

                              }];
    [task resume];
    NSLog(@"dataFetched, %@", dataFetched);

    return dataFetched;
}
```

So I have tried putting the dataFetched as a global variable so I could access it around my .m file and make it accessible to other .m file but when I tried to `NSLog` the dataFetched from other .m file it outputs (**null**). Is there anyway I could make the data accessible throughout my other .m files that needed the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use block with your method, instead of returning `NSDictionary`, So change your code like this.

First Change your method like this

```
-(void)fetchFromUrl:(NSString *)url withDictionary:(void (^)(NSDictionary* data))dictionary{ 
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest  requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:
                                  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                      NSDictionary *dicData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                    options:0
                                                                                      error:NULL];
                                      dictionary(dicData);
                                  }];
    [task resume];          
}
```

Now call your method like this

```
[self fetchFromUrl:urlStr withDictionary:^(NSDictionary *data) {
    self.dataFetched = data;
    NSLog(@"data %@",data);
}];
```

Comment: it worked! but how does this (void (^)(NSDictionary* data))dictionary works?

Comment: You are making an API call and that works in the background (async), and the the function that you declare with return `NSDictionary` is work in sync manner thats why when you get the response before that it will return the blank Dictionary, where as block work in async manner.

Comment: okay, it worked, but how am I going to access the data values? I tried using __block but it still not getting the values.

Comment: remove that __block, there is no necessary for that and that data is the dictionary that you want.

Comment: yes you are right, but I need that data to be available throughout the .m file because I need it to populate a UITableViewController cells.

Comment: Check my edited answer instead of `self.dataFetched` inside method use it when you call the method, now you can reload the table after initalization of `self.dataFetched`

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your `NSDictionary` inside the block you need declare `__block` attribute for your property like below

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) __block NSDictionary *dataFetched;
```

Look at [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

> Use __block Variables to Share Storage If you need to be able to
>   change the value of a captured variable from within a block, you can
>   use the __block storage type modifier on the original variable
>   declaration. This means that the variable lives in storage that is
>   shared between the lexical scope of the original variable and any
>   blocks declared within that scope.