# NSURLSessionDataTask returning nil value after getting response

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlsessiondatatask, jsonresponse, no-response

I created this api endpoint that sends back data about a person, and I'm trying to reach that endpoint from my app. I was able to connect to the endpoint but after calling that method it returns nil.

I've attempted to use a block statement to collect that data and returning that. I have also created a model that stores that data when there is a response which you will see below, but since it's an async task it seems like the data that I get back is still nil. I'm seems like I'm not capturing any data.

```
- (NSString *) verifyCode:(NSString*) code{
    NSString* ID = self.potentialPerson[@"ID"];

    [self validateInput:code :ID];//nil upon return
    return self->inputModel.CodeResponse;//returns nil
}

- (void) validateInput:(NSString *)code :(NSString *) ID {
    NSString *URL = [[inputModel api] stringByAppendingFormat:@"action=validate&code=%@&inputID=%@",
                          code, ID];
    NSLog(@"%@", URL);

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
    NSURLSession *sesh = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [sesh dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if([data length] >0 && error == nil) {
            NSLog(@"DATA WAS RECEIVED");

            NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

            self->inputModel.CodeResponse = [result objectForKey:@"messages"];
            //This outputs to console with the data I want
            NSLog(@"message: %@", self->inputModel.CodeResponse);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Data Error = %@", error);
        }}];
    [dataTask resume];//When it gets here the data in CodeResponse is nil

    return;
}
```

**EDIT** changes I've made since above code was posted. I followed Rob's suggestion  and I tried following this [How to get NSDictionary from NSURLSessionDataTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691246/how-to-get-nsdictionary-from-nsurlsessiondatatask)

I storage is null when it gets outputted to the console

```
- (NSString *) verifyCode:(NSString*) code{

    NSString* ID = self.potentialPerson[@"ID"];
    NSString *URL = [[inputModel api] stringByAppendingFormat:@"action=validate&code=%@&inputID=%@",
                          code, ID];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *storage = [self validateTypedCode:URL withDictionary: ^(NSDictionary *data) {
        self.CodeResponse = data;
        NSLog(@"message %@",data);
    }];
    NSLog(@"message %@",[self.CodeResponse objectForKey:@"message"]);
}

- (NSURLSessionDataTask *) validateInput:(NSString *)URL withDictionary: (void (^)(NSDictionary* data)) completionHandler {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest  requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:
                                  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                      NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                              options:0
                                                                                                error:NULL];
                                      if (completionHandler)
                                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                              completionHandler(result);
                                          });
                                  }];
    [task resume];
    return task;
}
```

Comment: You cannot **return** anything from a method which contains an asynchronous task. You have to use a completion block.

Comment: @vadian would creating a __block to store the data and returning that work? I've attempted that but for some reason it wouldn't work. Maybe you can explain why?

Comment: Put a `NSLog` statement where you try to `return` the code response. You’ll see it hits that line _before_ your `dataTaskWithRequest` block is called. That’s because that block is called “asynchronously” i.e. the execution of the current thread doesn’t wait for this network request to finish and call that block.

Comment: The bottom line, itsxqtar, is that you should give up on trying to return the value immediately. You should adopt asynchronous pattern, giving your `validateInput` method its own block parameter (similar to what `dataTaskWithRequest` does). This question has been asked and answered many times on Stack Overflow, so I’d suggest you search for that. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24852091/1271826

Comment: Thank you for the response. This was very helpful. I apologize for not seeing those other posts. I did some research but I guess not enough to see your response to those questions. @Rob

Comment: No worries: It’s a surprisingly hard to find relevant questions although there are hundreds permutations of it out there. The closest I could find used class method instead of instance method, and was returning the `NSData` instead of the parsed JSON object, but I hope you can see the parallels. This is an extremely common stumbling block when people first encounter asynchronous methods, but searches can be annoying difficult because the details vary from question to question (depending upon which asynchronous API they first stumble across this general class of problem). Don’t feel bad.

Comment: @Rob Hi Rob, I attempted to follow your suggestion from that post. Would you be able to provide more advice for me?

Comment: You have to put any code that needs the `CodeResponse` inside the block. You’re trying to print it in the line after the block, and as a result, again, it hasn’t been set yet because that’s called asynchronously (i.e. later). See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/3eb1bf3f484b3d0b865628503ddeb452